# Find the merge base between a remote and a commit

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Given a remote and a commitish, I want to merge it into a target branch on origin and generate a diff for it.

If the target branch exists in origin, it's a simple call to `merge-base` to check if the remote commitish is related to origin's tree and to get a diff from the merge base to the remote commit.

If it doesn't exist, blindly creating the new branch can be risky, as I want to make sure that the history being brought in is related to origin.

Right now, I'm using `rev-list` to determine if the commit has a shared history with origin. Specifically, I'm using `git rev-list --max-parents=0 --remotes=origin` and `git rev-list --max-parents=0 committish` to get the root commit(s) for origin and the remote commit and checking that they have at least one shared root (`rev-list` can generate the union or difference between commits/remotes but not the intersection it seems).

Now I know that the remote commit is related, but I still need to generate a diff. Right now, I only know what root commits in origin are reachable from the new commit. How can I find the best merge base in origin if I don't know which branch is the most closely related to the commit I want to bring in? Am I going about this completely wrong?

In other words, given origin and commitish, how do I identify the merge base X given no knowledge of the hierarchy of origin? `git merge-base origin committish` is not valid since origin doesn't specify a single commit.

```
o----o----o master        \
      \                    }-- everything reachable from origin
       o---X---o branch2  /
            \
o---o----o---o----o---o commitish    }-- new data from remote
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I going about this completely wrong?

I think so, yes.  Let's rewind and review.  I am sure you have seen some of this, but many explanations of this are ... not so good.  (Also, you've been revising your question while I have been answering, so we might be crossing a few wires...)

#### Remotes, remote-tracking branches, `gitrevisions`, and `git rev-list`

A *remote* like `origin` is just a name.  "A name for what" is a good question (not yours, at least not directly, but one you should ask).  The main "for what" is simple enough: for a URL.  The name `origin` stores a URL like `ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo`.  There is normally one URL attached to each remote.  (you can set a second, different one for pushing, if you like.  There are some rarely-useful cases where you can have more than one push URL as well.  But mostly it's just a short name for one URL.)  The key thing to remember here is not just that it's a name for a URL, but also that **there is another Git at the other end of that URL.**  That other Git repository has *its own* branch and tag names.

A remote name like `origin` is *not* a branch or tag.  By itself, it does not identify commits.  The things that *do* identify commits by name are your own (local) branch names like `master`; any tag names you have, such as `v1.3` if you have such a tag; and *remote-tracking branch names* like `origin/master`.  Each such name identifies *one specific commit*.  In the case of a remote-tracking branch name like `origin/master`, it identifies the commit your Git saw, the last time your Git contacted the other Git via the URL.  In other words, **remote-tracking branches remember what your Git saw the last time it talked to that other Git.**  They are only as up-to-date as your Git's most recent full conversation.  (Your Git will do partial updates on successful `git push` operations, but will only do full updates on `git fetch` operations where you have not restricted the fetch.  If you use `git pull`, it does a restricted `fetch`, which leaves at least some of your remote-tracking branches out of date.)

Somewhat confusingly, however, as [documented in `gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), the resolution path for an unqualified name *X* is:

1. See if `.git/X` exists; if so, use that.  (This makes sure that `HEAD` always means the HEAD commit.  As a side effect, it means you shouldn't name a branch `MERGE_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, or `FETCH_HEAD`, since various Git operations leave files with that name behind.)
2. See if `refs/X` exists; if so, use that.
3. See if `refs/tags/X` exists; if so, use that.
4. See if `refs/heads/X` exists; if so, use that.
5. See if `refs/remotes/X` exists; if so, use that.
6. **See if `refs/remotes/X/HEAD` exists**; if so, use that.

This very last one—item 6—means that using the remote name `origin` by itself will, if there's a `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, try that ... and Git now normally sets up a `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` indirect reference, pointing to the reference Git chose when you did your original `git clone`.<sup>1</sup>  This is usually `refs/remotes/origin/master` so that `origin` by itself *can*, but not necessarily *does*, "mean" `origin/master`, which *is* a remote-tracking branch name.

Meanwhile, [`git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) has its own special flags, including `--remotes`.  To understand these in all their full Git glory, you might want to refer as well to [`git for-each-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html), but they relate to the same search we saw above with `gitrevisisons`, and the idea that the reference name-space is hierarchical.

**All the remote-tracking branches for `origin` live within `refs/remotes/origin/`.**  That makes it easy for us to find them all.  And in fact, they're *constructed* by taking the other Git's branches—the ones that are local branches for the Git at the other end of the URL associated with the remote—and simply *renaming* them.  When you run `git fetch origin`, so that your Git has the full conversation with the other Git, your Git gets a list of all their branches, plus the specific commit IDs that go with those branches.  Then your Git changes their `refs/heads/X` to your `refs/remotes/origin/X` so that it can update your remote-tracking branches.

(Add `--prune` to get your own Git to *delete* any left-over remote-tracking branches you have, that no longer have a corresponding regular branch in that other Git repository.  Otherwise you may have a few ghosts left behind.  You can ignore the special "remote HEAD" entirely since it's an indirect reference, i.e., it merely contains the name of another remote-tracking branch.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Very old versions of Git didn't do this at all, and some older versions can't do it 100% correctly, but rather just guess.  Newer Gits can set the indirect branch correctly every time.  For some reason, though, it's set only on initial clone.  If you want to change it, you can at any time use `git remote set-head`, and you can set it to point to any of your remote-tracking branches, regardless of what's on the other Git.

---

#### Names that point to commits, and properties of (local) branch names

Above, I mentioned that these various names point to *one specific commit*.  This is in fact true of *all* names in Git.  The thing that makes branches special, different from tags for instance, is that branch names are expected to change over time, normally in an "add new commits" manner.

It's the commits themselves that point, backwards, to other (earlier / ancestor) commits.  As a key side effect or implication, this means that commits are typically on *many* branches, and that two different names may point to the *same* commit.

There's one other thing that matters a lot right here, and that is that a local branch name can have one (and only one) *upstream* setting.  If there is an upstream, it consists of two parts: the name of a remote, and the name of a branch as seen on that remote (i.e., "undoing" the remote-tracking-branch mapping).  This upstream setting tells Git what you'd like to merge with or rebase upon, when you merge or rebase.  By running the branch through the remote-tracking mapping (replacing `master` with `origin/master`), your Git can also tell you how far ahead and/or behind you are, of that remote-tracking branch.

(Of course, you have to run `git fetch` to *update* all the remote-tracking branches, before that last bit is useful.)

Now, I think we can get back to your question...

## What commit will you merge with?

> Given a remote and a commitish, I want to merge it into a target branch on origin and generate a diff for it.

I *think* what you are saying here is that sometimes, you just do not have enough information.

If you are given a *branch name*, you can get the target branch on origin:

```
$ git config --get branch.master.remote
origin
$ git config --get branch.master.merge
refs/heads/master
```

This tells us the same thing as:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref master@{u}
origin/master
```

with the obvious difference that the former is *not* mapped through to the corresponding remote-tracking branch, while the latter *is*.

If you are not given a *branch name*, though, there is no way to tell what the user wants to merge *with*—unless, of course, you take additional arguments.

This is in fact how `git merge` itself works:

```
$ git merge          # look up the upstream; merge with that
$ git merge 1234567  # merge with commit 1234567
```

The merge base of either merge will be the commit(s) found by `git merge-base` as run on both `HEAD` (the current commit, by definition) and `1234567` or `HEAD@{u}` (the target commit, or the default of the current branch's upstream).

Edit to add note: By the way, `HEAD` is *always* the current commit.  It's also *usually* the current branch name, because `HEAD` itself is usually an indirect (or *symbolic*) reference, naming the current branch, and the ID stored under that branch name is then the current commit.  Hence if you're "on branch master", as `git status` would say—in other words, if you'd have `* master` in `git branch` output—then `HEAD` contains the string `refs/heads/master`, and `refs/heads/master` contains the commit ID.  If you have a "detached HEAD", though, `HEAD` just has the raw commit hash in it, so that there is no current branch name.  In this "detached HEAD" case, there can be no upstream either, since the upstream is attached to the *branch name*.

Comment: I know the branch name, but if it doesn't exist in origin I need to make it and I want the history to share ancestry with the existing graph made up by origin's branches. That's simple.

The problem is finding the common ancestor between the new commit and all of origin's graph. So far I have `git rev-parse $(git rev-list --topo-order --reverse --max-count=1 $new_commit --not --remotes=origin)^` which gets the parent of the highest commit in the history of new_commit that is not referenced in origin. This would work, but only if the new commit's roots are a strict subset of origin's roots.

Comment: If there's no corresponding *name* in the Git on `origin`, there's nothing to merge with.  You'll need to ask that Git to set a branch name there, telling it which commit to set it *to* —and by definition, you can only ask it to set its branch name `foo` to point to some commit that you already have, because you ask by hash ID, from commits you have. These may be commits that you have, that they don't yet: you send them those commits with `git push`, and as the last part of `git push`, ask them to set the name as well. [continued]

Comment: If I'm reading your last comment correctly, you want to ensure that the commit you plan to ask them to set as their `foo`, connects at some point to some history that they already have, i.e., does not consist solely of all-new commits (once we follow that commit to its parents, and their parents, and so on). Is that correct?

Comment: That is part of it, but I've already solved that issue by computing the intersection of the root commits referenced by origin branches and the new commit. Now I need to calculate the diff of the new data introduced. In order to do that, I need to identify the closest commit in origin's history before the path leading to `new_commit` diverged.

In the example I posted, `git merge-base origin/branch2 commitish` returns commit X, which is what I want, but `git merge-base master commitish` will return the commit branch2 forked from.

Comment: That seems like a ... well, I won't say *bad* plan, but maybe "pointless"? At least, sometimes-pointless? Suppose for instance that the `push` will introduce just two new ordinary commits and that we can find the third one back, which is named `origin/startpoint` in our local copy, easily. If we now `git diff origin/startpoint foo` we see no change at all. But in fact, the *first* new commit changes everything, revealing all kinds of secret passwords, and the second change is a revert to undo it. We'll miss all the key stuff!

Comment: In general, it's unsolveable: Git does not record the place that a branch "splits off from", and all the labels are just labels. It's easy enough to find all commits reachable from label `foo` that are not reachable from any `origin/*` label; if you've run `git fetch` recently, these are the commits most likely to be pushed (but this will miss commits they can reach through their tags: you'd need "remote tags" to exclude those as well). You could then inspect all such commits to see what data you will send them.

Comment: I was afraid the only solution might be to brute force it, and I really don't want to do that. I don't know if I'd call it bad, but it definitely isn't ideal. We were hoping to have a way to reject (or log) incoming commits that delete or modify existing data as some people using the system are seemingly git-challenged. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're better-off doing that on the *server* side: it's easier there, since you have the information you want, in a pre-receive or update hook. You are given the reference name (branch or tag or notes ref), the old hash, and the new hash. For a simple update you can walk through all to-be-discarded and to-be-added commits and check them; for a new branch or tag name, you can use `--not --all` (not 100% perfect, but sufficient). See http://web.torek.net/torek/git/pre-receive.sh.txt for a moderately complex example pre-receive hook (doesn't scan commits though).